# Does Preview do something when copying bitmaps?

Tags: preview, image-editing

I had a jpg with text where I needed to exchange two words. My plan was to just copy the two words, apply a white rectangle on top of the original words to "erase" them and then paste the copied words on top of the white rectangle. But after doing so it looks like text is bolded or something like that.

Here is the original

[image: origina]

Here is the result

[image: result]

The differences becomes less obvious when zooming, but it is still there.

Original zoomed in 5 times

[image: Original @ x5]

[image: Result @ x5]

What's going on here? How do I avoid it?

Comment: What happens to the text when you re-save without doing that edit (but some other edit, like adding an annotation)?